# Does React-Admin <Pagination/> only works with data that have numric id?

Tags: react-admin

I am working with a back-end which provide id as string:

```
 "id": "c182a4f8-6729-4e5e-85a2-01e18eda8a67"
```

But i can't get the pagination to work in lists.

I tried the code with **fakeJsonServer** and pagination worked, the only difference that i could spot was the type of the id that fakeJson respons with

```
"id": 1,
```

is there any docs about this and how i can solve it?

Comment: It definitely works with string IDs (e.g. MongoDB ObjectIds). Maybe your API provider doesn't include the `total` field expected by react-admin (e.g. in a `Content-Range` header)?

Comment: it sends `X-Total-Count` does it make a difference?

Comment: Well, your data provider needs to account for that. If you're using the included `ra-data-simple-rest` provider, it won't work (though you should see a clear error message in that case). I'm really just guessing here, though – it could be a completely different problem. Maybe edit your question to clarify "can't get the pagination to work", i.e. include the error you're seeing, some relevant code snippets, etc.

Comment: i'm using a custom data provider (based on `ra-data-simple-rest` ) which checks for `X-Total-Count` rather than `Content-Range` but we changed backend to send  `Content-Range` and i used unmodified `ra-data-simple-rest`  but still the pagination doesn't work. this is the new header response:

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers →Content-Range`
`Content-Range →49`